# Missing Content in .xlsx files

Tags: apache-poi, xssf

So we have some standard `.xlsx` templates that when merged through Conga Composer, gives out an output `.xlsx` file. The problem is this output file is missing content from the original template file. This problem is only observed when we create a `XSSFWorkbook`. When we save the input template as `.xls` file the output is same as the input without any missing content.

```
    OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(new File("workbook1.xlsx"));
    XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
    ....
    workBook.write(fileOutputStream);
```

I would like to know why this behavior is observed only in case of .xlsx templates.

I will be glad to give further details about any other code snippets that would help.

Thanks in advance.